# analytics.js passing in timestamp

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, measurement-protocol

I am looking to implement Google Analytics using [analytics.js](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/) rather than ga.js. I would like to implement this into my hybrid HTML5 app which is served within an iOS shell. I am aware of the iOS SDK but I am trying to maintain one code base for different platforms.

I need to consider my app recording page impressions within a disconnected scenario, so I was going to store page impressions in localStorage and then when an internet connection is detected, then send each page impression individually to the Analytics service using the ga() function call.

In theory this works but I need to be able to send the page impression timestamp with each page rather than Analytics applying the timestamp when it hits their server.

Can this be achieved?

Thanks,

Rit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct the iOs sdk lets you use something called [Dispatching](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/dispatch) this allows you to send data that is up to 4 hours old.

This works directly with the Measurement Protocol where it is called [Queue Time](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#general)

> Used to collect offline / latent hits. The value represents the time delta (in milliseconds) between when the hit being reported occurred and the time the hit was sent. The value must be greater than or equal to 0. Values greater than four hours may lead to hits not being processed.

As far as I can see analytics.js doesn't allow you to do this, but it is just a JavaScript library that sends data to the Measurement Protocol.  It would probably be tricky getting that to work with Analytics.js which is probably why Google hasn't added it.

My advice to you is to store your data as you say locally then send it directly to Google though the Measurement Protocol.    Just remember it has to be less then 4 hours old, you will have to hope that network returns by then.

Comment: Thanks DalmTo, I see I can pass a payload directly to the Analytics endpoint URL https://ssl.google-analytics.com/collect. I can then send the pages viewed in a similar payload such as this and then include Queue Time...

v=1&tid=UA-123456-1&cid=5555&t=pageview&dp=%2FpageA

Can you see any issues with this approach that I could be missing?

Comment: Yes it is tricky but you can send it directly via the measurement protocol

Comment: This seems pretty straight forward... it feels like I am missing a trick :-)